# How to upload a file with other data in ASP.NET Core Boilerplate Application service?

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core boilerplate application service that supposed to receive a file and store it in the database with other various set of data. The file is represented as a `byte[]` and the others are strings, integers and lists.

```
// Application service
public class JournalsService : ApplicationService, IJournalsService
{
        private IJournalsManager _manager;

        public JournalsService(IJournalsManager manager)
        {
            _manager = manager;
        }

        public JournalDTO Get(int id)
        {
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Journal, JournalDTO>(_manager.Get(id));
        }

        public JournalDTO Update(JournalUpdateDTO journal)
        {
            Journal temp = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<JournalUpdateDTO, Journal>(journal);
            temp = _manager.Update(temp);
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Journal, JournalDTO>(temp);
        }

        public JournalDTO Create(JournalCreateDTO journal)
        {
            Journal temp = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<JournalCreateDTO, Journal>(journal);
            _manager.Create(temp);
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Journal, JournalDTO>(temp);
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            _manager.Delete(id);
        }
}
```

Both the entity and the DTOs have the file as `byte[]` and the other fields are string, int and lists.

```
    // Create DTO
    [AutoMap(typeof(Models.Journal))]
    public class JournalCreateDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ISSNPrint { get; set; }
        public string ISSNOnline { get; set; }
        public List<string> FieldsOfInterests { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }
```

and the entity :

```
 // Entity
 public class Journal : Entity, IHasCreationTime
 {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        public string ISSNPrint { get; set; }
        public string ISSNOnline { get; set; }
        public string FieldsOfInterests { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        public Journal()
        {
            CreationTime = Clock.Now;
        }
}
```

In swagger UI the file field required to be a string (maybe a string of bytes) but i need it to be a byte[] and i need the file upload to be in the application service . I searched in the boilerplate documentation and searched in official forum but with no luck .

So how to implement a method for receive a file upload ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For uploading file in swagger UI, you will need to change `application/json` to `form-data`.

Follow steps below:

1. Add `FileOperationFilter`[Source Code](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/aspnet-core/blob/365dc9ccb19d21feef4cd270b012e301b82765c1/src/EdwardAbp.Web.Host/FileOperationFilter.cs#L14) to support `form-data`.
2. Register `FileOperationFilter` in `Startup.cs`

   ```
       services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
       {
           options.OperationFilter<FileOperationFilter>();

           options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "EdwardAbp API", Version = "v1" });
           options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

           // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
           options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new ApiKeyScheme()
           {
               Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
               Name = "Authorization",
               In = "header",
               Type = "apiKey"
           });
           options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
           // Assign scope requirements to operations based on AuthorizeAttribute
           options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
       });
   ```
3. Change `public byte[] Image { get; set; }` to

   ```
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
   ```
4. Change Operation by adding `[FromForm]` for the model which contians `IFormFile` property.

   ```
   public async Task<OrderDto> CreateOrder([FromForm]OrderDto input)
   {

   }
   ```
5. After accessing swagger, you will be able to upload file by click `Choose File`.
   [image]